# Use pre-trained model vocabulary in an appropriate way with allennlp

Tags: vocabulary, allennlp

When using a huggingface pre-traind model,i passed a tokennizer and indexer for my textfied in Datasetreader, also i want use the same tokennizer and indexer in my model. Which way is an appropriate way in allennlp ? (using config file ?)
Here is my code, i think this is a bad sloution. Give me some suggestions please.

> `In my Dataset Reader::

```
    self._tokenizer = PretrainedTransformerTokenizer("microsoft/DialoGPT-small",tokenizer_kwargs={'cls_token': '[CLS]',
                                                                                    'sep_token': '[SEP]',
                                                                                                  'bos_token':'[BOS]'})
    self._tokenindexer = {"tokens": PretrainedTransformerIndexer("microsoft/DialoGPT-small",
                                                                  tokenizer_kwargs={'cls_token': '[CLS]',
                                                                                    'sep_token': '[SEP]',
                                                                                    'bos_token':'[BOS]'})}
```

> In my Model:

```
self.tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-small")

num_added_tokens = self.tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'bos_token':'[BOS]','sep_token': '[SEP]','cls_token':'[CLS]'})

self.emb_dim = len(self.tokenizer) 

self.embeded_layer = self.encoder.resize_token_embeddings(self.emb_dim)
```

I have create two tokenizers for datasetreader and model, and both the tokenizers have the common vocabulary and special tokens. but when i add the three special token in the same order, the special token will have a different index. so i switched the order in Model`s codes to achieve the same indexs.(stupid but effective)
Is there exists a way to pass the tokennizer or vocab from DatasetReader to Model?
Which way is an appropriate way in allennlp  to slove this problem ?

Comment: Do you actually need the tokenizer/token indexer in your model, or do you just need access to the tokenizer's vocabulary? Because your can access the tokenizer's vocab in `self.vocab` from the model.

Comment: I have readed the guidience of allennlp's vocabulary, and I think i need to use the pretrained model'` vocab as my vocab , not from the instances. @petew

Comment: The vocab that's passed into the model's `__init__` method will contain the word pieces from the huggingface tokenizer. It reads out the huggingface tokenizer and puts the tokens there.